# Reduce number of database IO or size of data operation?

Tags: mysql, database

To make the system more efficient, should we reduce the number of database IO or reduce the size of data operation?

More specifically, suppose I want to get top 60-70 objects.

**1st approach**:

By joining several tables, I got a huge table here. Then sorting the table based on some attributes, and return the top 70 objects with all its attributes and I only use the 60-70 objects.

**2nd approach:**

By joining less tables and sorting them, I got top 70 objects' ids, and then I do a second lookup for 60-70 objects based on their ids.

So which one is better in terms of efficiency, esp for MySQL.

Comment: This is sort of a vague question, but chances are, option 1 will be cheaper.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you want to reduce the number of calls to the database. But as always with performance, you shouldn't be guessing - Measure what you got, make adjustments and then compare the effect before and after. Keep in mind that these factors may change over the life time of the application (As data volume goes up, or number of users/traffic goes up)

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on how you designed your query.

Usually `JOIN` operations are more efficient than using `IN (group)` or nested `SELECT`s, but when joining 3 or more tables you have to choose carefully the order to optimize it.

And of course, every table bind should envolve a `PRIMARY KEY`.

If the query remain too slow despite of your efforts, then you should use a cache. A new table, or even a file that will store the results of this query up to a given expiration time when it should be updated.

This is a common practice when the results of a heavy query are needed frequently in the system.

You can always count on [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to measure the speed of your queries and play with your options.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, the best way to take advantage of query optimization is to combine the two approaches you present.

```
 SELECT col, col, col, col, etc
   FROM tab1,
   JOIN tabl2 ON col = col
   JOIN tabl3 ON col = col
  WHERE tab1.id IN
   ( SELECT distinct tab1.id
       FROM whatever
       JOIN whatever ON col = col
      WHERE whatever
      ORDER BY col DESC
      LIMIT 70
    )
```

See how that goes? You make a subquery to select the IDs, then use it in the main query.

Comment: I'm unsure if MySQLs optimizer doesn't already do this sort of thing. I mean, possibly (if the optimizer is good enough) MySQL would only use the JOINed tables when they are actually used in the WHERE clause in the first step. If that is the case, the subquery is useless and may be even more inefficient than writing a JOINed query straight away - what i *think* is the case.

Comment: On my experience this sort of query is terribad. Its like MySQL repeats the nested SELECT for each row or something stupid like that.

Comment: @Havenard thats only when you use a subquery in the SELECT part of your query. Using subquerys as a derived list in the WHERE clause or as a derived table for JOINing is not bad in general, but *may be useless* and *may render the optimizer unable to to its optimization correctly*, depending on the use case.

Comment: I wish it was the case, but it seems its not. One thing I know for sure, if you try the same query but hardcoding the IDs you want inside that group instead of a runtime SELECT, it can run hundreds of times faster.

Comment: Just found more reference as to what i'm talking about: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/ *TL;DR:* [It’s pretty common knowledge that MySQL doesn’t yet optimize subqueries very well in some cases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html), and this particular problem is widely reported. In most cases, it’s safer just to stay away from subqueries if they’re not needed — especially WHERE... IN() or WHERE... NOT IN() queries.

Comment: @Havenard and I think we're talking about the same thing here. Generally speaking, sometimes MySQL decides to optimize the query going from outer to inner, and not inner to outer. ("inner to outer" is what the query author mostly wants the database to do - like in this answer, or example) The `WHERE col IN(subquery)` case is explicitly described in the [MySQL manual as a restriction for subquerys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html)